# Maphpix gives the comands in Latex of a picture?

Tags: transformation

I downloaded Mathpix snip but when I was convet to .tex file it just put an includgraphics.  I'd like the commands in Latex in order I can edit the formulas. Is this because I'm trying a free version?

Could you give more options?